# Why Same Image src is retrivied every time

Tags: jquery

On parsing an xml file , i am creating img tags dynamically and appending it to a div as shown

```
activateUiHTML.append('<img id="imageds" type="img" height="40" width="40" value="'+image[i]+'" src="'+image[i]+'"/>') ;
```

When i am trying to retrieve it , i am always getting the same src  , I tried with this

```
var srdd = $("#imageds").attr('src');
```

and

also tried

```
//  var stcc = document.getElementById("imageds").src
```

but always i get the same image src every time

http://jsfiddle.net/6yF9U/

could anybody please tell me why .

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context... `$("#imageds")` will always (on most browser) matches the first element with ID equal to `imageds`

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't use the same `id` on more than one element, [`id`s must be unique in the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). If you use an `id` on more than one element, then anything looking up that `id` has to guess which one you want. Most implementations use the first one, but as using the same `id` on more than one element is invalid, that's not guaranteed.

If you want to look up the element later, you need to give it a unique `id` (or similar). For instance, you might use `imageds1`, `imageds2`, etc., and then `$("#imageds1")`, `$("#imageds2")`, and such to look them up.

Comment: can anybody please help me even though i assign a new id , how can i know that id dynamically when retriving ?

Comment: @Kiran using any event handler, `this` inside it will refer to this specific element. That's said, you should use common class instead, imho. And btw, you should start to follow some basic tutos.

Comment: Already this is inside an event handler , should i put another event handler for images into that ??

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because you are using id selector in a loop, so you have more then one object with id that have to be unique. That's bad:)